# Scarlett 2i2 1st Gen not detected on my windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I bought the Scarlett from someone who is using this using in MAC devices, and I am trying to use it in Windows 10.

When I plugged it into the USB the light gets blinked and it gets detected, and immediately the light gets off and the windows don't recognize it. This happens when I plugged it and it goes away.

[image: it blinks and goes off]

However, when I press the phantom power, it is getting the power from the USB.

[image]

I have also installed the driver related to it, but no luck. I have installed the driver from this site for Windows 10.

https://downloads.focusrite.com/focusrite/scarlett-1st-gen/scarlett-2i2-1st-gen

But, how can I make this device recognizable from Windows 10?

What could be the problem with this device not working on my PC?

Comment: Though I don't know the Scarlett specifically, this type of device often needs to be connected at boot, not afterwards. Try that & report back.

Comment: did that and tried. didn't work.

Comment: Is it plugged directly to the computer itself, not via a hub of any sort?

Comment: yes it is plugged directly to the USB

Comment: and i did tried to hub also but no luck

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. I'd contact Focusrite.

Comment: Check out this: https://www.musictoob.com/focusrite-scarlett-2i2-not-recognized-solved-for-mac-and-windows-users/#Solution_for_Windows_Users

Answer (score 1):

Focusrite
[advises](https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/206849399-Why-are-the-gain-or-USB-LEDs-flashing-constantly-on-my-bus-powered-Scarlett-iTrack-Solo-Windows-)
using a mains-powered USB dock.

There are several posts I have found
([example](https://www.reddit.com/r/Focusrite/comments/pi1lqf/my_scarlett_solo_is_blinking_green_and_is_not/))
that also remark that the computer can't generate enough power,
and especially for a laptop.

You could also try another (shorter) USB cable.

To submit a request to Focusrite, use the
[Submit a request page](https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/requests/new0).